# Computer can't find more than ~8000 unique strings?

Tags: c++, random

I wrote little app that draws numbers in binary system without duplicates for me. It works perfectly for 2, 4, 8 bits but when it comes to 16 app can't find more than ~7,8k combinations.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

string IntToString(int integer)
{
    ostringstream ss;
    ss<<integer;
    string Converted = ss.str();
    return Converted;
}

bool IsAlreadyDrawed(string what, vector <string> where)
{
    for(int i=0; i<where.size(); i++)
    {
        if(where[i]==what) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

vector <string> FillIt(int HowManyBits)
{
    vector <string> Randoms;
    int random;
    string lol;
    do
    {
        for(int i=0; i<HowManyBits; i++) lol+=IntToString((rand()%2));
        if(!IsAlreadyDrawed(lol,Randoms))
        {
            Randoms.push_back(lol);
            cout<<"Pushing in "<<lol<<endl;
        }
        lol.clear();
    }
    while(Randoms.size()<pow(2,HowManyBits));

    return Randoms;
}

void ShowIt(vector <string> What)
{
    cout<<"\n";
    for(int i=0; i<What.size();i++) cout<<i+1<<". "<<What[i]<<endl;
    getch();
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    ShowIt(FillIt(16));
}
```

Comment: That `FillIt` function looks extremely inefficient. Why don't you just create a vector of all 2^HowManyBits strings (in order) and then randomly shuffle the vector?

Comment: @AnukulSangwan It is C++ per the C++ specification, which is the official word regarding what is C++ and what is not C++.  Anything else is just, like, your opinion, man.  :)

Comment: @Michael Firstly, I want them to be in order, secondly I'm trying to do the vector with 2^HowManyBits strings by generating them, checking if they are in there already and if not then adding them?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Care for a citation? I cannot find the text "conio" in either the C++ or the C standard.

Comment: Don't use `pow(2, *x*)`.  Use the left shift operator, as it is a lot more efficient.  Many processors have instructions that perform shifting.  Calling `pow` requires function call overhead plus algorithm stuff, plus returning code.  A lot more code than a single shift instruction.

Comment: _"I'm trying to do the vector with 2^HowManyBits strings by generating them, checking if they are in there already and if not then adding them"_ Which is very inefficient, because you're very likely to be generating a lot of strings more than once. Like I said, it would be better to just generate all possible strings once and then shuffle them.

Comment: The `conio.h` file is a platform specific header providing interfaces for more advanced console operations than `cout` provides.  One cannot determine the exact language based on the inclusion of this non-standard file.

Comment: You could replace the `IsAlreadyDrawn` function with the `std::find` method.  If you use `std::set<std::string>` you don't need to concern about duplicates, as the `set` does not allow duplicates.

Comment: What "C++ specification"? @JeremyFriesner Please point me to it.

Comment: Also, prefer to pass `std::vector` by const reference, if the vector contents are not modified, or by reference.  Otherwise, the `std::vector` object is placed on the stack (taking up more stack space) and then popped off; where passing by reference allows direct access.

Comment: @Michael "it would be better to just generate all possible strings once" but how?

Comment: @stevenhawkingsbiggestfan: Easy: `for(int i=0; i<(1<<HowManyBits); i++) Randoms += IntToBinaryString(i, HowManyBits);`  (where `IntToBinaryString` is some function that converts an integer to a binary string with N digits, e.g. `IntToBinaryString(3, 2)` should return `"11"`).

Comment: You can replace the `IntToString` function call with this `ternary operator`:  `lol += (char)((rand() % 2) ? '1' : '0');` or the equivalent `if` statement.  No need to convert an integer to string.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I don't get what "? '1' : '0'" is for

Comment: The ternary operator can be replaced with an `if` statement:  `if (rand() % 2) {lol += '1';} else {lol += '0';}`, where '1' is the *character* 1 and '0' is the character zero.  Also, the bit can be tested with arithmetic `&`, such as `if (rand() & 1)`.  Sometimes the `&1` expression is translated more efficiently than the `%2` expression.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews So compiler will take "(rand() % 2)" result as true/false? (1 = true, 0 = false) am I thinking right?

Comment: Close.  Being pedantic, 0 == `false`, all other values are `true`.

Comment: @Michael so your idea is that I should just add every number from 1 to 2^HowManyBits converted into binary to Randoms?

Comment: Everybody is nitpicking your code but not addressing the problem, which is that the low order bits of a linear congruential random number generator are not very random. You need a higher quality random number generator or at least extract a higher order bit. Also, as you get closer to filling the array, it gets harder to find numbers that haven't been seen.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks, I have never seen that but it makes code shorter

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I tried `void ShowIt(vector <string> &What)` but it doesn't work (passing by reference).

Comment: @stevenhawkingsbiggestfan: Yes. And after you've done that you should shuffle the elements in the vector randomly (since I assume that you want the strings in random order).

Comment: @Michael No, I want them order, thanks!

Comment: @AnukulSangwan C++ specification is available here:  https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard   The part of the C++ specification that says you can #include a file (including a file named conio.h) is in section 16.2